# Create node only if it doesn't exist in py2neo v4

Tags: py2neo

My understanding of neo4j is that we can use `Merge` to add a node in such a way that we won't get duplicates. The py2neo v4 documentation says that

> For a GraphObject, create and merge are an identical operation

Yet when I execute the following code, I get 3 nodes in my graph:

```
graph.create(Node("Person", id="Bob"))
graph.create(Node("Person", id="Bob"))
graph.create(Node("Person", id="Bob"))
```

How can I add a node while also checking that the node doesn't already exists?